# What is the meaning of proof of a proof?

Tags: proof-theory, computer-assisted-proofs

After reading about [Curry-Howard corrsepondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence) and looking at some proofs written in coq i've thinked about meaning of proof of a proof.

1. We can express proofs as a computer program
2. Proof is correct when program compiles
3. We can test compiled program or even write correctness proof for it.

So, what test of a proof checks? What correctness proof of a computer-program-proof will prove? Proof correctness is ensured on compilation stage, what is the meaning of proof of a proof? Is there any meaning?

Comment: After that, if we automate proofs of proofs, we can worry about proofs of proofs of proofs.  This could go on forever, unless proving something actually means _understanding_ something, which is what the automated part omits.

Comment: *Understanding something* doesn't really have a concrete meaning, so there is actually no "unless".

Comment: Is this not actually extremely deep, essentially playing on the fact that one has to leave an axiom system in order to prove that it is consistent?

Comment: Proof is socially constructed concept. You will never have an 'objectively' bulletproof proof.

Comment: I think "understanding something" does have an important meaning, but not one that admits of mathematical definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lewis Carroll, in 1895, recognized the infinite regress possible.

See 
"What the Tortoise Said to Achilles"
here:
http://www.ditext.com/carroll/tortoise.html

Answer (score 1):

I think your description of Curry-Howard correspondance is not precise enough:

2. The proof is correct if the program is well-typed and has as type the formula to be proved.

**Any** well-typed program of the right type is a correct proof of this formula, you don't need to check 'correctness'.